# Critical Points of Square Root Multi-variable Function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am confused how would I find the critical points for this question. I used chain rule on the whole function and also tried using chain rule for each individual number or variable but I am unsure what to do after that. The question is as follows:

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2-4x+5}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it suffices to consider the radicand $f(x, y) := x^2 + y^2 - 4x + 5$. The necessary condition $\nabla f = 0$ leads to the equation system

\begin{align} 2x - 4 &= 0 \\ 2y &= 0 \end{align}

with solution $(x, y) = (2, 0)$.

Comment: Why would it suffice to consider the radicand only and completely ignore the square root? ( I was under the assumption chain rule was necessary in order to answer the question)

Comment: Because $g(x) = \sqrt{f(x)}$ becomes minimal (maximal) if and only if $f$ becomes minimal (maximal) by the monotony of $\sqrt{\cdot}$. Note that you can of course take the chain rule and derive in order to get $g'(x) = f'(x) / (2 \sqrt{f(x)}$, but then it also has to be $f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: I'm still confused with your explanation. For the chain rule I had (x-2)/(sqrt(x^2+y^2-4x+5) what would I then do after that to still get the same answer?

Comment: This expression is $0$ iff $x = 2$. But you also have to take the partial derivative with respect to $y$, this will give you $y = 0$.

Comment: Oh I see now! When you say take the partial derivative with respect to y are you referring to the numerator not the denominator?

Comment: You have to calculate the partial derivative with respect to the square root as you did with $x$. This gives $\partial_y (\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - 4x + 5}) = 2y /(2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - 4x + 5})$ and this is $0$ iff $y = 0$.

Comment: Ok that makes sense! and when we are looking for the critical point of the questions we simply look at the numerator not the denominator after using chain rule?

Comment: Yes, because you know that a fraction $a/b$ is equal to $0$ iff $a = 0$.